# Feature class with spatial subcategories ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-pro, feature-class

I have two polygon feature classes in ArcGIS Pro, one is coarser than the other. For example: let's say feature class 1 shows the extent of a house, whereas feature class 2 shows the extent of the rooms inside the house.

Now it would be nice, if I could merge those two feature classes into one feature class (or into another data type?). The only problem is, that I want to retain the geometries of both feature classes. Meaning I'm looking for something that displays the coarser feature class on a map, but where you can expand the polygons of the finer feature class as needed (as subcategories?). It should be in one dataset, so we can export the attribute table  as an Excel file.

I think that this is not possible in ArcGIS. However, I want to use the knowledge of the masses. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can proceed here?

Comment: It sounds if you want to use [Representations](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/draw-layers-with-representations.htm).

Comment: Do you have big differences in the extent or precision of these two files? If not, I don't see why you cannot easily merge them. As Yogesh C. suggests, then play with classes and scale-based visibility. It sounds like you want something like raster pyramids but for vector data.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way here is to first apply spatial join that would allow you to "***Joins attributes from one feature to another based on the spatial relationship. The target features and the joined attributes from the join features are written to the output feature class***". And later play around with symbology that can vary according to scale as well as attributes.

[https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm#:~:text=A%20spatial%20join%20matches%20rows,to%20the%20output%20feature%20class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm#:%7E:text=A%20spatial%20join%20matches%20rows,to%20the%20output%20feature%20class).